# JSONPath expression to search for objects with certain property in different tree branches

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am looking for a JSONPath expression that returns all zone objects with zoneType "big".

Input JSON:

```
{
  "board" : {
     "zones" : {
          "1": {
              "zoneID": 1, 
              "zoneType":"big" 
           },
           "2": {
              "zoneID": 2, 
              "zoneType":"small"
           },
           "3": { 
             "zoneID": 3,
             "zoneType":"small" 
           },
          "4": {
              "zoneID": 4, 
              "zoneType":"big" 
           },
       }
   }
}
```

Expected Output:
              [{
                  "zoneID": 1, 
                  "zoneType":"big" 
               },
               {
                  "zoneID": 4, 
                  "zoneType":"big" 
               }]

I have tried:
$..zones.[?(@.zoneType='big')]
$..zones.*[?(@.zoneType='big')]

and many others but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

i too initially used jsonpath then later got stuck with some problem so decided to use 
looping through the data.so can you try with the below piece of code.

var json = ur json data;

var output = (function (data) {

```
var keys = (function (obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
})(data["board"]["zones"]);
var categoryFilter = new Function('data,keys',
        "obj=[];" +
        "for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){" +
            "if (data[keys[i]].zoneType == 'big') {" +
               "obj.push(data[keys[i]]);" +

            "}" +
        "}" +
        "return obj;"
        );
return JSON.stringify(categoryFilter(data["board"]["zones"], keys));
```

})(json);

Answer (score 0):

Answer should be: $..zones[?(@.zoneType=="big")]

Following works :-

JsonPath.on(json_hash, '$..zones[?(@.zoneType=="big")]')

returns:-

[{"zoneID"=>1, "zoneType"=>"big"}, {"zoneID"=>4, "zoneType"=>"big"}]

Answer (score 0):

JSONPath is unstandardised "query language" but XPath is. Using DefiantJS, you can query JSON structure with XPath expressions. This library extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and it returns matches as an array like object.

Below is example code (and here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/DQ9CJ/):

```
var data = {
       "board": {
          "zones": {
             "1": {
                "zoneID": 1,
                "zoneType": "big"
             },
             "2": {
                "zoneID": 2,
                "zoneType": "small"
             },
             "3": {
                "zoneID": 3,
                "zoneType": "small"
             },
             "4": {
                "zoneID": 4,
                "zoneType": "big"
             }
          }
       }
    },
    found = JSON.search(data, '//*[zoneType="big"]'),
    str = '';

for (var i=0; i<found.length; i++) {
    str += found[i].zoneID +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```